# Make server unavailable gracefully using Powershell in ARR

Tags: iis, powershell, arr

We are using ARR as reverse proxy and I would like to make a server unavailable for various reasons. How can this be done using Powershell?

**Edit 1:**
I found this http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/11/09/using-arr-config-extensibility-to-gracefully-stop-server.aspx tutorial for using JScript. But I'm not able to translate it to powershell.

**Edit 2:**
Using the Set-WebConfigurationProperty in WebAdministration module I'm able to changes settings for a server. I found SetState in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\arr_schema.xml` but I don't know how to invoke that method.

Comment: I believe this link will be of help:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1156563.aspx I've used it myself, and it works rather nicely. Matt

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your server farm is named myWebFarm and the server you're trying to set to drain is myNode1, the following PowerShell code will do the trick

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$arr = Get-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "webFarms/webFarm[@name='myWebFarm']/server[@address='myNode1']/applicationRequestRouting" 
$setState = $arr.Methods['SetState'].CreateInstance()
$setState.Input.Attributes['newState'].Value = 1
$setState.Execute()
```

If you want to check the value of currentRequests counter to see when it has finished draining (goes to 0), you can use

```
(Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "webFarms/webFarm[@name='myWebFarm']/server[@address='myNode1']/applicationRequestRouting/counters" -Name "currentRequests").Value
```

In general, the Generate Script feature of Configuration Editor in the IIS Manager GUI can be helpful in generating PowerShell scripts to get you at least part way there.

Comment: If it helps anyone else 'newState' Value can be set to the following Enum values: Start, Drain, GracefulStop, ForcefulStop